# Maven Release Patterns

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to maven, and trying to understand how to release my project.  I have the following project setup in svn:

```
trunk
  |-deployer
  |    |-pom.xml
  |-webapp
  |    |-pom.xml
  |-utils      
       |-pom.xml
```

While developing **webapp**, I always want to develop against the latest snapshot version of utils, so I declare the dependency on utils in webapp/pom.xml via:

com.company
      utils
      1.0-SNAPSHOT

Webapp itself is also currently versioned at version 1.0-SNAPSHOT.  It's pom.xml has the declaration:

```xml
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Sample Webapp</name>
```

So everything is working great, but now I want to release my software.  In deployer, I have the following in pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>deployer</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Project Release</name>

  <modules>
    <module>externals/webapp</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <url.svn>http://<my-server>/<project>/trunk</url.svn>
  </properties>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:${url.svn}</connection>
  </scm>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <tagBase>
            http://<my-server>/<project>/tags
          </tagBase>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>Releases</id>
      <name>Releases</name>
      <url>http://<nexus-server>/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>Snapshots</id>
      <name>Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://<nexus-server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Within the deployer folder itself I have a folder called "externals" which has an svn-externals set to check out my webapp project (I added this because maven complained about not being able to find it), so my modules path should be correct.

**Questions**

1.)  I want to release a version of my web app, but when I run a `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` in my deployer project, my only tangible output is my trunk tagged in svn and a pom uploaded to my nexus repository.  This makes sense in that my deployer artifact packaging is type "pom", but it also doesn't get the job done of getting me a war of my webapp (I should note here that if a do a release in the webapp project by itself though, that I will get the war).  I need to release multiple modules, and so I thought I could use maven aggregation from the deployer project to accomplish this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

2.)  Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the maven-release-plugin against each module that you intend to release. I've never seen someone have a special "deployer" module that releases the other modules, this is not how things are commonly done.

Normally to release the webapp module you would run the commands against the webapp module, and to release the utils module you would run the commands against the utils module.

If you have a parent module that ties webapp and util together then I believe you can just run the release commands against that.

Comment: what purpose does maven project aggregation serve if there is no  output?

isn't my deployer in this case the parent module?  the only output was that it tagged trunk and published itself as a release pom artifact

Comment: I missed that you are declaring `<modules>` inside the deployer pom, so it should act similar. But I think the difference in your case is the use of svn-externals to "check out" the webapp source. The maven-release-plugin does all that on it's own. Also traditionally the parent POM would be in a parent directory to the child modules. Take a look at this writeup which might help you: http://onjavahell.blogspot.com/2009/12/releasing-multi-module-project-using.html

Comment: if you remove the externals folder, I get an error saying the maven says that the child module pom.xml does not exist.  I have a separate deployer project because i may have multiple deployment scenarios where I need diff deployers and that would clober a single parent pom.xml.  i think i can remove the externals and just make Jenkins check out the additional project as you can use relative paths in the modules tag, but my deployment problem persists.

Comment: The path to the module needs to be correct, so you'd probably want `<module>../webapp</module>` or something. This is why the parent project pom is usually in the parent folder of the child module.

Comment: As for deployment, I would consider that a separate concern from building and releasing your project in Maven (where "releasing" really just means publishing a new versioned artifact somewhere). I don't think Maven is the right tool for deploying apps to servers. And to be clear, the release-plugin does the SCM work for you already - verifies you have no files locally not in your SCM, builds and tags the project, then checks out by that tag to do the final release and upload of the new release version. You don't need to fully reinvent all these wheels.

Comment: right.  i suppose my project should be renamed "releaser" then.

Comment: i had some misconfiguration in my releaser project.  the scm.url needed to be:  scm:svn:${url.svn}/releaser to match up with what was in svn.  then it did exactly like what your answer says.. it ran the target against each module and put the artifacts into nexus.

Comment: if you are doing this with maven project inheritance, you will need to include the maven parent as a module

Answer (score 0):

As matt b says, simply adding a maven-release-plugin entry at the top pom will probably do what you want. If you want to collect several artifacts into a proper release bundle, you want to create a module for this, but then you want to look at the maven assembly plugin. It can collect various jars (wether from modules or external dependencies) and resources into a directory, zip file or similar.

Comment: i have a release plugin at the top (see deployer pom.xml).  matt b was saying to run it from each module separately.  i'll check out the maven assembly plugin.  that looks interesting.  thanks.